# Blender 2.93 Cycles render does not work

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I was on the latest version before this, 2.92. Everything was fine.
I just updated, I clicked to import settings from 2.92 at the first run popup window, all ok.
Then I loaded one of my scenes, everything ok.
But now, if I try to render, the viewport remains grey, and once I try to revert the viewport to EEVE render, the program simply enters an infinite loop and freezes.
The grey space in the middle of the image is the object "rendered" in "Cycles".
[image]

And this below is what happens after I click another render method: menu stuck and mouse pointer rolling.
[image]
The same happens if I switch to another panel with a different render method.

Update: this only happens when using GPU computer. If it's on CPU, it works. I have just tried with a brand new scene with the cube, where Cycles is set on CPU, and it worked.
Once I tried to switch to GPU, again it rendered grey.
Then when I reverted again to CPU, the program froze.

Comment: Are you using Viewport Denoising ? If you do, you have to wait a bit before it is fully initialized the first time you launch a new version, and I experienced that it is way longer than before in newer versions. It tends to crash everything if you try to change back before it's finished. My advice : Go into rendered mode, go make coffee or have a shower, and come back, it should be good to go then

Comment: Doh! Thank you for advice, I'll try it right away!

Comment: @Gorgious
It worked!
Took some 5 or 10 minutes, but when I came back the viewport showed the render, and I can now switch back and forth in render modes and panels, no problem.
Thank you!
I suggest you write this comment as an answer, so you get your score!

Comment: However color+albedo and color+albedo+normal work, but color alone will cold crash Blender and exit.

Comment: Glad it helped :) I'll write that as an answer then. If you have a hard crash every time you switch to color you should report this as a bug (Help > Report a bug) hopefully it will get fixed in the next release

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using Viewport Denoising, the algorithm has to pre-load a number of things. I'm sure it is very technical so I won't even try to understand what it does under the hood, but the point is you have to wait for a bit and it's best if you don't touch your keyboard or click anywhere while it's working. You only have to do it once every new release.

I experienced that it is way longer than before in newer versions.  (2.93 and 3.00 beta)

It tends to crash everything if you try to change back before it's finished.

My advice : Go into rendered mode, go make coffee or have a shower, and come back, it should be good to go then.

Comment: This is HUGE, thank you!!  I have been racking my brain about why the new version simply won't use Cycles.  Just had to wait about 10 minutes and viola!  Thanks again, you're a champ ;)