# Cycles Not Available in 2.93

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Tried opening an existing project (created in 2.92) in 2.93 and Blender freezes on render.  Then I discovered that when I reset the program to defaults, cycles is no longer available.  However, it is enabled in Add-ons.  Am I missing something?

NOTE: I have tried enabling "filter add-ons" in the Workspace settings, to no avail.  The other topic "why is cycles render engine missing" is not relevant to my issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried resetting the preferences? Or did you go to File>Defaults>Load Factory Settings?

Comment: I did, yeah, no effect.  But I found another question about the same issue and someone said to just wait a while and the software would eventually initialize and the problem would go away.  Waited about 10 minutes and viola! No more issue.  Thanks for taking the time to chime in, much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to link to another topic but just in case anyone comes across this... this answered my question:

[Blender 2.93 Cycles render does not work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/224493/blender-2-93-cycles-render-does-not-work?rq=1)